# How to clean your build with Flutter RP2 in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter

With the release of FLutter Release Preview 2 using Android Studio 3.1.4 my project has sporadic build issues when I stop the program from Android Studio with the command stop 'main.dart' (command f2) and then do a run 'main.dart' (^R) I get the error listed below. Yet if I totally close Android Studio and open the project again, it compiles and runs correctly without the error.  I'm wondering if there is a way to clean the project to elevate having to close and open Android Studio, this is sort of counter productive to Flutter hot reload.

Here's the Android Studio error that I get:

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"04e99281-55ea-41cd-851f-5b07487c5302","id":"0","progressId":null,"message":"Initializing gradle..."}}]Initializing gradle...

Resolving dependencies...
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
*registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
compiler message: lib/ui/loginScreen.dart:1:1: Error: Can't access platform private library.
compiler message: import 'dart:_http';
compiler message: ^
Compiler failed on /Users/pbirdsall/Documents/highline/hl_leverage/lib/main.dart*

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/pbirdsall/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 460
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.

  > Process 'command '/Users/pbirdsall/flutter/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1

You can ignore the following part of the error log (in italics above), as this occurs on a successful execution of the program.

deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) compiler message: lib/ui/loginScreen.dart:1:1: Error: Can't access platform private library. compiler message: import 'dart:_http'; compiler message: ^ Compiler failed on

My version of Android Studio is 3.1.4

My version of Flutter is:

Flutter 0.8.2 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5ab9e70727 (2 weeks ago) • 2018-09-07 12:33:05 -0700
Engine • revision 58a1894a1c
Tools • Dart 2.1.0-dev.3.1.flutter-760a9690c2

I'm running on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Menu `Tool` > `Flutter` > `Flutter Clean`

or in a terminal window in the project directory

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: Unfortunately the flutter clean didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Then you shouldn't accept my answer ;-) I don't know how to fix your error.

Comment: It does answer my specific question, even though it does not correct the error. Your answer is helpful for anyone else inquiring on this question.

Comment: You could create a new question with the remaining problem. It's unlikely someone checks answered questions.

Comment: Tried so many ways. But this worked for. thank you very much.