# I got this Samsung (7.1.1) device that I am using to make an app. When I try to run the app directly to the device it shows an error saying

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, adb

i got this error

> adb: failed to install C:\Users\User\Documents\BukuTamu\bukutamu\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: Failure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1558851448.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line#7): Requires newer sdk version #29 (current version is #25)]
>   Error launching application on SM P355.

Comment: Do you mind posting your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: https://github.com/lutfiadysh/build.gradle/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: what is your new error after modifying your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Cannot be! Make sure your apk is rebuilt with the new settings

Comment: but how? im new in flutter sorry

Comment: See how to clean the app https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485825

Comment: thank you so much !!! the error was solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to modify your `minSdkVersion 25` and `targetSdkVersion 29` inside your `build.gradle`.

**Explanation:**

The reason for this error is that you are trying to install an APK built with higher version of minimum Android SDK (constrained by `miniSdkVersion` insdie `build.gradle`), but your device Android environment (in other words, your device Android SDK) is lower than the `minSdkVersion`, i.e. for your case, it is 25 (according to error message "current version is #25").

And also, according to below error message, your current `minSdkVersion` should be 29, which is not suitable for your SM P355 device.

> Requires newer sdk version #29 (current version is #25)] Error launching application on SM P355.

Comment: This is backwords. His device is not supported, and he needs to switch his minimum SDK from 29 to 25 if he wants to support his older device.

Comment: i have do that but nothing happen

Comment: You need to change your minsdkversion instead of your targetsdkversion, and remove any functions that require a higher sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Your minimum SDK is set to 29 but you're running 7.1.1 which has an SDK of 25. Update your device if you can, or lower your project's minimum SDK. Remove any functionality that requires SDK 26+

If you lower your minimum SDK you lose out on some functionality but Nougat is really not that old and should probably be supported unless there is something that you really need in your project from later versions.

Change your minSdkVersion to 25 in your build.gradle

Comment: how can i lower my minimum sdk version ?

Comment: In build.gradle there should be a line that says minSdkVersion with a 29 after it, change this to 25.

Comment: i have change minSdkVersion to 25, and remove any functionality that requires SDK 26+

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?